# How to use Excel VBA to conditionally add and delete certain rows in a table

Tags: excel, vba, data-analysis

I have a table with following columns

**Date,  Employee name, Task#, Hours, day of the month**

each row contains information for all the columns.

All I am trying to do is to combine (find SUM of hours) of certain rows based on the following criteria/conditions:

add and combine rows when following is true

1. has same date
2. has same employee name
3. rows containing task# starting with "LBR" except "LBR 30", "LBR 28"
   (there are some more LBR# exceptions as seen in my code)

   OR the rows has only the exception LBR (LBR 30, LBR 28..)

   OR the rows that has only Non LBR task#

in other words, for a certain date and employee name, I only want to have rows for three different categories

1) total "LBR" hours (not including exceptions)(determined by column "Task#")

2) total "LBR" hours (only the exceptions once) (determined by column "Task#")

3) total non "LBR" hours

Example:

```
Date        Employee            Task    Hrs Dom
6/4/2019,   Wright  , Stephen,  CND05,  30, 4   
6/1/2019,   Wimberly, Robert,   LBR16,  30, 1    
6/1/2019,   Wimberly, Robert,   CNRWK,  30, 1    
6/1/2019,   Wimberly, Robert,   A02060, 30, 1    
6/2/2019,   Wimberly, Robert,   LBR16,  30, 2    
6/2/2019,   Wimberly, Robert,   A03000, 30, 2    
6/2/2019,   Wimberly, Robert,   A03000, 30, 2    
6/2/2019,   Wimberly, Robert,   LBR30,  30, 2    
6/2/2019,   Wimberly, Robert,   LBR28,  30, 2    
6/2/2019,   waja,               A02060  30, 2    
6/2/2019,   waja,               A02060, 30, 2
```

I want to convert it to this:

```
Date        Employee            Task    Hrs Dom
6/4/2019,   Wright, Stephen     CND05,  30, 4   
6/1/2019,   Wimberly, Robert,   LBR16,  30, 1    
6/1/2019,   Wimberly, Robert,   CNRWK,  60, 1    
6/2/2019,   Wimberly, Robert,   LBR16,  30, 2    
6/2/2019,   Wimberly, Robert,   A03000, 60, 2    
6/2/2019,   Wimberly, Robert,   LBR 30, 60, 2    
6/2/2019,   waja    ,       ,   A02060, 60, 2
```

What I did is any two rows with similar date, name, and task category(one of three categories), I took sum of their hours and retained one row (deleted anyone and kept the other)(NOTE: it can be more than two rows that needs to be combined).

I first sorted the table to according to date, name and task# and implemented the following code

```
Sub SortAndSum()

Dim R As Integer
Dim PR As Integer

Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet

Set wkb = Excel.Workbooks("LaborHours.xlsx")
Set wks = wkb.Worksheets("srg.hours")

R = 6

Do While wks.Cells(R, 2) <> ""

PR = R - 1
If wks.Cells(R, 1) = wks.Cells(PR, 1) Then
    If wks.Cells(R, 2) = wks.Cells(PR, 2) Then
        If InStr(1, wks.Cells(R, 3) & wks.Cells(PR, 3), "LBR") = 0 Then GoTo SumAndDelete
    ElseIf InStr(1, wks.Cells(R, 3) & wks.Cells(PR, 3), "LBR") = 1 Then
        If wks.Cells(R, 3) & wks.Cells(PR, 3) = "LBR10" Or "LBR28" Or "LBR29" Or "LBR291" Or "LBR293" Or "LBR295" Then GoTo SumAndDelete
        ElseIf wks.Cells(R, 3) & wks.Cells(PR, 3) <> "LBR10" Or "LBR28" Or "LBR29" Or "LBR291" Or "LBR293" Or "LBR295" Then GoTo SumAndDelete

SumAndDelete:
wks.Cells(R, 4) = Cells(R, 4) + Cells(PR, 4)
wks.Rows(PR).Delete

        Else
        GoTo NextRow
        End If

End If


NextRow:
R = R + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

problem with my code:
-I have to run this code multiple times to get my final result. 
- when dealing with LBRs, i get run time error 13, TYPE MISMATCH. when i click on "Debugg" button, it highlights the following part of the code:

```
ElseIf wks.Cells(R, 3) & wks.Cells(PR, 3) <> "LBR10" Or "LBR28" Or "LBR29" Or "LBR291" Or "LBR293" Or "LBR295" Then GoTo SumAndDelete
```

Comment: When deleting rows you need to loop **backwards**

Comment: There are also many other issues with your setup - get rid of the `GoTo`s, and your `Or`s need to each test against something.

Comment: @dwirony only if you do it inefficiently ;-)  ...step one, figure out which rows to delete - `Union` them; step two, delete them all in one single operation; that way no need to loop backwards, no recalcs and repaints occurring between deletions, etc.

Comment: I don't understand your last 2 `If` statements - the first one says "Delete these rows if it contains these LBR values", then the one proceeding it says "Delete these rows if it **doesn't** contain these LBR values".

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Yes that's true. After looking at this code a second time I realized there are more issues than the order of the loop at hand :)

Comment: Some column headers in your sample data would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

@dwirony . The third last if statement only determines the possibility of first two category cases (referring back to my description right before my example).  So the last two if statements checks for the  first and 2nd category respectively.

Also, I wanted the code to run the last two if statements only when the third last if statement was true. Not sure what's actually happening.

@MathieuGuindon @dwirony thanks for your feedback. Any other suggestions?